# Will PowerShell 3 script run on Windows 7?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Will a PowerShell 3 script that contains PowerShell 3 cmdlets run on a vanilla installation of Windows 7 Professional or Enterprise?  If not what are the minimum prerequisites required?

(Sorry, Powershell newbie)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 7 from installation is with Powershell version 2.0.

For Powershell v. 3.0 you need  [Windows Management Framework 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) on a
windows 7 sp1 and .net framework 4

Answer (score 3):

As Christian notes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13397332/67392): there are PowerShell V3 install for Windows Vista, 7, Server 2008 R2 and Server 2008.

But note:

- To upgrade ISE (Integrated Scripting Environment) that feature must be enabled *before* applying the V3 install (this affects servers which default to no ISE).
- If the script depends on cmdlets introduced by the Windows 8 or 2012 OS or its components (eg. Hyper-V's) these are not part of PowerShell V3 and are not added as part of the V3 upgrade.